# Optaplanner workbench - Chained planning entity

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible at this stage of the Optaplanner workbench, to illustrate Chained planing entities ? I am dealing with a routing problem that has to decide physical paths of links for assigning overlay links.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OptaPlanner Workbench **6.4.0.Final** does not support chained planning variables yet.

A future version will support it.